# Reaction of aluminium chloride with alkali metal

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I wonder if we can get aluminium metal by adding alkali metal (ex. Li,Na) to aluminium chloride solution?

or

maybe what will happen if we mix aluminium chloride hexahydrate with sodium metal?

Comment: I am not sure about alkali metals but you can try manganese: https://patents.google.com/patent/US3900312A/en

Comment: If there is water in solution or in the hydrate, hydrogen would be released with priority.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some sodium metal to any aqueous solution will only produce the reaction $\ce{2 Na + 2 H2O -> 2 NaOH + H2}$, whatever the nature of the solute (containing Al ions or not). The same reaction happens with aluminium chloride hexahydrate. To get an aluminium production with metallic sodium, the aluminium chloride has to be anhydrous. This was discovered by Davy in the years 1800 - 1810.